# Print 1,5,9,13....from the sequence 1,2,3,4,5.....using Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have to create a list of every 4n+1 term from the list of natural numbers [1,2,3.....] using Haskell

I could write this program using some examples :

```
elem' n xs = case drop (4*n) xs of
              (y:ys) -> y : elem' n ys
              [] -> []
```

This will generate a list of every nth element in the original list.

But my code is not giving the correct result. Can anyone point out where it is going wrong ? Should I not use drop and do some recursion ?

Comment: Why do you use `4*n`? Isn't `n` the "iterator", that thus says indexes `1, 5, 9, 13, `...

Comment: I thought that for 4*n, n =1 being 4, it will drop the first 4 elements and give me the 5th element.

Comment: but then were does the `4*` comes in?

Comment: One other way could be `map ((+1) . (*4)) [0..]`

Comment: If you are interested in help debugging your own code, post the incorrect output, and make a guess as to why you're getting that result instead of the correct one.  It is very effective to try understand what's wrong *before* trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the use of recursion over infinite list. Something like this should do the trick.

```
run :: [Int] -> [Int]
run (x:xs) = x : run (drop 3 xs)
```

Beware that `run` returns an infinite list so you should take only a finite number of elements.

```
take 10 $ run [1..]
```

Comment: Basically it's the implementation of the solution suggested yesterday by @Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 3):

If you aim to generate the sequence *1, 5, 9, …*, then you can write this as:

```
[1, 5 .. ]
```

Indeed, this generates a list like:

```
Prelude> [1, 5 .. ]
[1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29,33,37,41,45,49,53,57,61,65,69,73,77,81,85,89,93,97,101,105,109,113,117,121,125,129,133,137,141,145,149,153,157,161,165,169,173,177,…
```

If you aim to obtain the elements at these indexes, you probably do not need `n`. *n* is here the "*iterator*" so to speak, it says that for every *n*, we access the *4×n+1* element, so you "skip" each time three elements:

```
obtain4_1 :: [a] -> [a]
obtain4_1 [] = []
obtain4_1 (x:xs) = x : go xs
    where go (_:_:_:ys) = obtain4_1 ys
          go _ = []
```

For the list of items `[1..]`, this gives us the same values:

```
Prelude> obtain4_1 [1..]
[1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29,33,37,41,45,49,53,57,61,65,69,73,77,81,85,89,93,97,101,105,109,113,117,121,125,129,133,137,141,145,149,153,157,161,165,169,173,177,181,…
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was wondering if it is possible to replace the go (_:_:_:ys) by using some recursion to make it more general ? Like we can supply an integer n to skip every three elements

Comment: @2014GAM: you can use `drop` to drop a number of elements from the list, and thus continue recursion with the rest of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Taking advange of haskell [List Comprehension](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension), you can write a function like this:

```
obtain :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
obtain 0 _  = []
obtain n x = [ a * x + 1| a<-[0..n] ]
```

With n we pass how many items of the list we want and with x you can generate any (x*i + 1) secuence.

Sample test cases:

```
*Main> obtain 10 4
[1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29,33,37,41]
*Main> obtain 10 3
[1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28,31]
*Main> obtain 10 2
[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21]
*Main> obtain 15 2
[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31]
*Main> obtain 5 1
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

If you need the nth element of the generated list you could write a helper function for that.